# Can I template operator overloading for operator<<

Tags: c++

I have these two overloaded operator<< functions.  Can I use the template system to condense these to 1 function?

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<glm::vec3>& vertices){
  for (auto i = vertices.begin(); i != vertices.end(); ++i){
    os << glm::to_string(*i) << '\n';
  }

  return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<glm::ivec3>& vertices){
  for (auto i = vertices.begin(); i != vertices.end(); ++i){
    os << glm::to_string(*i) << '\n';
  }

  return os;
}
```

Comment: They are the same Oo

Comment: @amchacon, vec3 vs ivec3

Comment: Yes. Does this answer the question you *wanted* to ask?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a *function template* and  `std::enable_if` in order to have a single function which works with both `glm::vec3` and `glm::ivec3`:

```
template <typename T>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vertices)
    -> std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_same<T, glm::vec3>::value || std::is_same<T, glm::ivec3>::value,
            std::ostream&>
{
  for (auto i = vertices.begin(); i != vertices.end(); ++i){
    os << glm::to_string(*i) << '\n';
  }

  return os;
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/u5dKwp0MsBrkgKwt)

---

If you want to instead support *every type that works with `glm::to_string`*, you can use *expression SFINAE*:

```
template <typename T>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vertices)
    -> decltype(glm::to_string(std::declval<T>()), std::declval<std::ostream&>())
{ 
    // ... as before
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HVYxkBNq9tgFfMDw)

Comment: I love new C++ templates :)

Comment: @amchacon: Nothing really new here.

Comment: @Jarod42 what about std::enable_if_t?

Comment: Restrict on `glm::to_string(*i)` would make the function more generic btw.

Comment: I tried your wandbox example and get this:
prog.cc:14:9: error: ‘is_same_v’ is not a member of ‘std’
         std::is_same_v<T, glm::vec3> || std::is_same_v<T, glm::ivec3>

Comment: @mikeglaz: you need to include `type_traits`. If it still doesn't work, try `std::is_same<...>::value`.

Comment: @amchacon: Can mostly be done in C++03, it is just now in `std` (`_t` can be done since c++11, in std in c++14). just syntaxing sugar. but with `decltype`, I would agree ;)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo 

prog.cc:13:8: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::enable_if<(std::is_same<T, glm::vec3>::value || std::is_same<T, glm::ivec3>::value), std::basic_ostream<char>&>::type’ because ‘std::enable_if<(std::is_same<T, glm::vec3>::value || std::is_same<T, glm::ivec3>::value), std::basic_ostream<char>&>’ is a dependent scope

Comment: @mikeglaz: `enable_if_t<...>` doesn't need `typename`. `typename enable_if<...>::type` does. What compiler are you using?

Comment: ok the problem was I was using -std=c++11.  Your first example works.  The decltype one compiles but nothing gets printed.

Comment: I'm using g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609. In my print() function I have `std::cout << vertices << std::endl;` and only the newline is being printed.  Sorry, but I've never worked with decltype's and declvalue's.